# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, matplotlib

As my code wasn't working I tried a simpler version:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.hist([1,2,3,4,4],bins=15)
```

and it gives me the error: AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'items'
I've updated some versions recently but I find nowhere from where the error could come from. 
Btw I have 3.5.1 version of matplotlib.

Can someone tell me how to make plots work again please ?

Comment: On Windows 10 64-bit in Python 3.10 with `matplotlib==3.5.1`, I am unable to reproduce your error. Please create a new virtual environment and try again - something else must have messed up your environment. What version of Python are you on?

Comment: @Grismar
I have python 3.8.5 and I'm on MacOS
My latest conda update also ruined other libraries like sklearn, shuffle for example doesn't work anymore
The thing is this is my root environment, should I uninstall python and install everything again ?

Comment: If you have these issues in your global environment, I would recommend starting over and to avoid having to do that again in the future, start using virtual environments to do your work in. I typically keep a `sandbox` environment around that has all manner of stuff installed, for experiments, while projects run in their own environment with only the packages they actually need.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the same setup. Reseting you virtual environment will probably fix the issue.

Comment: You likely did an update/upgrade to matplotlib without closing and restarting your interpreter. I was able to reproduce by doing that.